# SQL: How to update column with unique values

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is a MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS counted, employer_group
FROM
    employer_survey
GROUP BY employer_group
HAVING counted > 1;
```

Before I alter table definition for `employer_group` to unique, I need to create an `UPDATE` statement to `CONCAT()` the value of `created_dt` to `employer_group` so the alter table will not fail because of values.

How do I do this? I am unable to return `id` column because I am using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

I should mention that I want the `id` column returned so I may use the above `SELECT` with an `IN` clause in my `UPDATE` statement. This may not be the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `join`:

```
update employer_survey es join
       (select es2.employer_group
        from employer_survey es2
        group by es2.employer_group
        having count(*) > 1
       ) eg
       on es.employer_group = eg.employer_group
    set es.employer_group = concat_ws(' ', es.employer_group, es.created_dt);
```

Comment: Your query has a typo. Please change from 'employee_group` to `employer_group`. Also when I executed, it affected 936 rows but my query above only returns 219 rows. How should the join be modified to only update 219 rows?

Comment: Never mind. The number of rows affected are correct. I have updated the query in your answer to correct your typo.